# Как сделать страницу с ошибкой 404?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть статический сайт на чистом HTML. Как мне сделать редирект с несуществующих страниц на существующую статическую `.ru/404.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно внутри файла `.htaccess` ввести следующее:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
```

А затем редактировать сам файл `error.html`
(назвать файл можете как угодно, главное, чтобы его название совпадало с тем, которое находится в `.htaccess`)

Comment: Искренне благодарю, то что надо!